# Display a django-from from JS

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

so here is the thing i have a block of html code that needs to be replaced when a button is clicked. Its no big deal using

```
$('div.myCustomReplacer').replaceWith(newHTML);
```

but i also need to render a django-form `{{ form }}` in the new HTML
when i simply use
`<div class="NewDiv"> {{ form }} </div?` the html is rendered as `"{{ form }}"` because of those quotes the form is not rendered.

So how i do remove those ?
sorry just new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve it like that. Remember that the form is added when html is rendered in the server, so basically `{{form}}` doesn't exist in client.

No worries, there are several simple ways to reach you goal just using simple JavaScript. One way is to simple let server inject the form, and just make it visible when user click button. Take a look at the example I made for you.

```js
document.getElementById('showBtn')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.display = 'block';
  });

document.getElementById('hideBtn')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
button {
    margin: 1rem;
}
section {
    margin: 1rem;
}
section span {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    font-size: small;
    padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hide Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="showBtn">Show Form</button>
    <button id="hideBtn">Hide Form</button>
    <section>
      <div id="targetDiv" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Form <span> (a moment ago I was just hidden)</span></h2>
        <form>
            <label for="someInput">Bla bla</label>
            <input id="someInput" type="text"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer ! it didi solve it other issues i was facing ....I am using django-croppie to crop images before i upload them. <div id=cropper></div> is where my croppie is rendered. so when i button is clicked i am just replacing my current html content with the div required my croppie. but i also have to render the form after it, {{ form.media }}